# Display error Woocommerce admin edit product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display an error message on the Woocommerce admin edit product page. I've tried using `add_settings_error()`, but it didn't work. I read about the way Woocommerce displays [errors](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8104), but can't seems to get it to work as it all seems related to the Settings API. 
I'm using `get_option()` to retrieve an option on the Admin edit product page. If it's not set, I want to raise an error, with a link to the settings page. What's the best way to display an error on this page?

Comment: As WooCommerce is a WordPress plugin and product a WordPress custom post type from WooCommerce, you should may be read [Complete Guide to WordPress Admin Notices](https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/) *(article/tutorial)*…

Comment: I had read this page a number of times, but after reading it again, I found a method that works, and hooked into 'admin_notices' instead.

Comment: So you could add it as an answer that will be useful to this community… Thanks.